# structure padding for big endian and little endian machines

Tags: c, endianness

I am going through  compiler takes care of aligning as mentioned in following link.

http://vcfaq.mvps.org/lang/11.htm

I generalize my question under what scenarios we have to align programmatically and what scenarios compiler will do that for us?

Does padding requires if two machine with differient endian types i.e., one m/c is big endian and other is little endian and communicating through TCP/IP protocol does padding requires for this?

Kindly clarify my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You only have to worry about padding and alignments when you are sending raw structures through `write()` (or whatever your function is). Check with your compiler documentation on how you can force the compiler to turn off padding, and align on 1 byte boundaries, if sending structs is what you really want to do. Only do this in the networking layer though, because you are effectively turning off data optimizations for the architecture you are compiling for. If you are using the structs in application specific algorithms (lots of reads and writes), you **will** lose performance, if you fiddle with alignment and padding settings.

Also, you also have to make sure that all fields of the structure is in an endian order that both sides have agreed on. Padding and alignment does not affect endianess.

Answer (score 1):

TCP/IP defines the network byte order as Big-Endian. Computers with a Little-Endian architecture must reorder the bytes in the TCP/IP header information into Big-Endian format before transmitting the data and upon receiving it.

All of the protocol layers in the TCP/IP suite are defined to be big-endian.

Padding/alignment is not affected by endianness.

Comment: TCP/IP defines only the byte order for the parameters that are within scope of the protocol itself. The payload can be in whatever order the two end points agrees on (preferably).